# Suggested edit from 2012 in review queue?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, suggested-edits

I just had this edit in the review queue, which was apparently from November 2012: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7622388

Image for reference:

[image: Old suggested edit in review queue]

Is this a bug, or was this edit really in the queue for more than 2 years?

Comment: There's more of them. Just entered the queue and found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7622460) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7622461). The rest seems to be recent.

Comment: I got [one](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3471/review-a-minor-suggested-edit/3491#3491) on Unix & Linux as well. The editor (now with 17K+ reputation), still got his +2 rep!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We tracked down a bug in suggested edits where around 100 were missed.  We decided to just add them to the queue using the original creation date of the suggestion.  Once these are cleared you shouldn't see suggestions older than a week or so.

Comment: Wow, that's 100 edits where even the authors didn't realize they were pending. Scary!